# Singlely linkedlist copy confusioin

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes

Suppose we have a single linked list `1->2->3->4->5` and `1` is the `head`

```
ListNode newHead = new ListNode(0);
ListNode p = newHead;  
ListNode runner = newHead; 
newHead.next = head; // Line 1 p and runner next is also head
while(n>0){
    runner = runner.next; // Line 2 why newHead and p does not move along with runner just as above because they are equal object (I assume)
    n--;
}
```

Why don't `p`, `newHead` and `runner` all change at the same time? In `Line 1` they do, but in `Line 2` they don't, why?

Comment: Where do you define `head` ? Line 1 seems to be used to make the while loop work for the head of the list too.

Could you also explain the expected behavior of the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume `newHead` is at memory location `A`.
Since you assign `newHead` to `p`, `p` now points to memory location `A` as well.
Same logic for `runner`, pointing to `A`.

Now you set some property of the `newHead`, which "changes" the property on all three `newHead`, `p` and `runner` since all point to the same object in the same memory location `A`.

If you now write `runner = runner.next` you assign a new value to `runner`.
Now `runner` points to memory location `B`.

But that simply does not matter for `p` and `newHead` since they only pointed to the same location as `runner` but had no other relation than that. They only pointed to the same location / the same object. If you change the object all three know of that change. But if you change where one of the three points to, that does not matter for the other two.

Java non-primitive variables are simply pointers / references to memory addresses where the actual object lies. Without you as the developer having to deal with the problems that might arise from pointers (or having access to the features they provide).